# zsh: Line starts with empty character followed by username. How to remove this extra space?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am very new to zsh. I just installed zsh and oh-my-zsh. When I run the terminal I see the following picture:

[image]

You may see that in zsh the line starts with space followed by a username. To compare in bash the line starts with username immediately.

How can I remove this first space in zsh? (I can't find this config setting in docs)

Comment: Fix the prompt! (`PROMPT` or `PS1` or whatever you are using). Have a look with `echo "'$PS1'"`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. PS1 looks like this: `%f%b%k$(build_left_prompt)`. Now I am trying to figure out what is build_left_prompt and how to modify it.

Comment: Note that I suggested to use `echo "'$PS1'"` and not `echo "$PS1"`, so you can easily see a leading space. Aside from this, since %f%b%k are not supposed to produce any visible character, I agree that `build_left_prompt` is producing the space. What happens if you invoke it manually, maybe as `xxd <$(build_left_prompt)`, so that you can see better what's going on?

Comment: When I execute `build_left_prompt` directly, it returns the following string:
`%K{000} %F{003}%n@%m %K{004}%F{000} %F{000}~ %k%F{004}%f % `

Comment: There is a space between %K{000} and %F{003}, and this is the space you are seeing.

Comment: Yep, but I can't find a way to fix/override this function. If I just add it to my .zshrc it totally destroys my prompt.

Comment: You can always redefine a function. Find the source code of this function and either update it in place, or insert it at the end of your .zshrc and apply the changes you need to. Since it is likely a function from the _oh-my-zsh_ package (I don't use it, so I don't know), and you think it is an error in the function definition, please create a bug report for it.